# GGplot2: Single study design

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a graph to show a single case study in ggplot2. Other R packages have been created to deal with this kind of data but I rather use ggplot2. So, here's my issue.

This is a very basic graph but I would like to separate the line that connects all dots in two parts, based on the Phase. So the first 8 dots should be linked by one single line, then the line should stop and then connect from dot 9 to the last one. The same information should be used to draw the vertical line in geom_vline.

```
library(ggplot2)

Phase <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
Rate <- c(8, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 8, 7, 18, 15, 9, 8, 17, 19, 11, 11)
db3 <- data.frame(Phase, Rate)

ggplot(data = db3, aes(x = seq_along(Rate), y = Rate)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line() +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 8.5, linetype = "dashed", color = "blue", size = 0.5) +
      xlab("Occasions") +
      ylab("Ratings")
```

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**

This is the final outcome that I have. Although I can draw the line manually, I would rather use the information in *Phase* to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add color = Phase to line aesthetic

```
   ggplot(data = db3, aes(x = seq_along(Rate), y = Rate)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_line(aes(colour = Phase)) +
   geom_vline(xintercept = (sum(Phase=="A")+0.5), linetype = "dashed", color = "blue", size = 0.5) +
   xlab("Occasions") +
   ylab("Ratings")
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, I would like to draw the vertical line automatically. I updated my post above

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, you just want to split the line in two pieces, which could be done by grouping the data based on *Phase*:

```
ggplot(data = db3, aes(x = seq_along(Rate), y = Rate)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = Phase)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 8.5, linetype = "dashed", color = "blue", size = 0.5) +
  xlab("Occasions") +
  ylab("Ratings")
```

Additionally, adding the color aesthetic would make your groups more obvious:

```
ggplot(data = db3, aes(x = seq_along(Rate), y = Rate)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = Phase, color = Phase)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 8.5, linetype = "dashed", color = "blue", size = 0.5) +
  xlab("Occasions") +
  ylab("Ratings")
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Also, I would like to use that information not to use a number in geom_vline(xintercept = ...)